# Calling a class inside a class during type declaration in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, nested

This is the structure of data that I need

```
this.nodes=[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'root1',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
        { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'root2',
      children: [
        { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'child2.2',
          children:[
            {id:7, name:'child2.2.1'}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ];
```

For data type declaration I need to write a class which goes something like this

```
export class EvaluationMapperNodes {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    children: EvaluationMapperNodes[];
}
```

Using `EvaluationMapperNodes` inside itself is giving error. but the depth of children is dynamic.
How do I recursively call class inside it.

P.S. Its Angular 2 project.

Comment: When you ask a question, never say "is giving error". Instead please show the exact error it is giving. Also check that the code sample you post actually shows the error: your `EvaluationMapperNodes` class as you posted it works just fine, so your error is elsewhere but as you didn't give any detail of the error there is nothing to answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Change your interface like :

```
export class EvaluationMapperNodes {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  children?: EvaluationMapperNodes[];
}
```

---

The Error you must be getting because of this part

```
...
children: [
    { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
    {...
```

As it does not contain the `children` property, so it should be `optional`, and that you can achieve by using `?` before property name like

```
children?: EvaluationMapperNodes[];
```